# How do I actually package and move my code, say for a production deployment using Docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I realize there are all sorts of different strategies and Dev Opsy architectures to deploy Docker containers to production, but I'm still learning some of the basics of Docker and I'm really looking for the most straight forward way to move the following example, into say AWS or another remote site.  I think I understand how to setup projects in various containers, link them, etc.  But I don't understand how to save or package my existing code and deploy it elsewhere.

Here is a sample template that I am trying to work off of.

**Docker-Compose**

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - redis:redis
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

redis:
  restart: always
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  volumes:
    - redisdata:/data
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

This Dockerfile just creates a directory called 'code' which is where I assume the actual development will take place. ie; run docker compose, containers are created and then start developing in the code directory.  So let's say I'm done with whatever I'm working on and now I deploy to production using the exact same template above, won't this Dockerfile just create an empty 'code' directory in AWS?  What about the work I'm trying to deploy from the code directory on my local machine?  How do I package the actual code directory to move to production?

Comment: Do I just create a new image from my project and then deploy that new image with a new Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

The result of your `docker build` should be an image that contains all of the commands, scripts, compiled code, and interpreted code needed to run your application anywhere. Your developers may inject their own copy of this code into the image with a volume mount while they are making changes to avoid constantly rebuilding the entire container (though docker's layer caching does shorten the build time).

Once built, you `docker push` your image up to a registry server, e.g. Docker Hub, or you can run your own (docker has a registry image in addition to their own commercial offering) or use one provided by a third party like AWS. Then your production environment should `docker pull` and run this image when you deploy to production.

Comment: In my example, docker build would not run my application anywhere I'm guessing because my dockerfile creates a new directory to start a new Django project in.  Each time I run a Docker build an empty directory is created.  I'm guessing I need to create a new Dockerfile that imports my existing code?  Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly.